# JQuery UI Dialog Not Showing when using a separate JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to Javascript and JQuery and i want to create a basic social website. I got stuck on the login page though. What i basically want the website to do is when you click Login a dialog will popup and say that your password and username are not correct and two buttons to say sign up and cancel. I understood you can do that using JQuery Dialog UI but im struggling doing it. These are my HTML, Javascript and CSS page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
        <!-- include the jquery library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- include the jquery ui library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 // show the dialog when submit is clicked and checked
 function showDialog(){
    /* select the div you want to be a dialog, in our case it is 'basicModal'
    you can add parameters such as width, height, title, etc. */
    $( "#basicModal" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Are you sure?",
        buttons: {
            "YES": function() {
                window.open('signup.html');
            },
            "NO": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>


    </head>
<body>

<section class="loginform">  
<form name="login" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return check(login)" accept-charset="utf-8">  
    <ul>  
        <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>  
        <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required></li>  
        <li><label for="password">Password</label>  
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>  
        <li>  
        <input type="submit" value="Login" ></li>  
    </ul>  
</form>  
</section>
    <!--
    -this is the actual dialog, yes, it is included in your html body, it is just hidden
    -we did not set the dialog 'title' here, we set it in the js parameter
-->
<div id="basicModal">
   You mad? Username and Password are not correct. Please sign up using the button below.
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript Page

```
function check(form) {
/*the following code checkes whether the entered email and password are matching*/



    if (form.username.value === "user" && form.password.value === "pass") {
        window.open('home.html'); /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    } else {
        //alert("Password or Username Not Found. Please sign up."); /*displays error message*/
        showDialog();
    }

}
```

And my css

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.loginform {

    margin: 20% auto;
               width:200px;
}

/* dialog div must be hidden */
 #basicModal{
        display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your `check` function doesn't return anything. It has to return `false` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Dialog still not shown.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u23g7/ Not sure if this will be useful. Never worked with jsfiddle. I just want the JQuery dialog to popup when username and password does not equal to user and pass. But it does not apparently

Comment: I changed the fiddle to use the `No wrap` option, otherwise the `check` function isn't in the global scope and never gets called. then I get the alert: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/u23g7/1/

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of `showDialog()`. There shouldn't be `);` after the closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` from the `check()` function to prevent the form from submitting:

```
function check(form) {
    /*the following code checkes whether the entered email and password are matching*/
    if (form.username.value === "user" && form.password.value === "pass") {
        window.open('home.html'); /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    } else {
        //alert("Password or Username Not Found. Please sign up."); /*displays error message*/
        showDialog();
        return false;
    }
}
```

You also have a syntax error. There shouldn't be `);` at the end of `showDialog()`.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/u23g7/4/)